# Check box :checked by condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a check box  and I want the checkbox to be checked if a parameter equals 1.  So I need the :checked to only be true if the condition is true.

```
<%= check_box_tag 'catalog_image', 1, :onclick => 'this.form.submit()', :checked => (params[:catalog_image] == 1)%>
```

The current condition I am testing does not work.  The param will automatically be added, or subtracted, when the form submits because it is linked back to the same page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The API say:
[Rails check_box_tag](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/check_box_tag)

```
check_box_tag(name, value = "1", checked = false, options = {}) public
```

So you can improve this in one single line:

```
<%= check_box_tag 'catalog_image', 1, <CONDITION>, :onclick => 'this.form.submit()' %>
```

Answer (score 4):

Use if to this, because the presence of the `:checked` tag that matters, not it's value

```
<% if params[:catalog_image] == 1 %>
   <%= check_box_tag 'catalog_image', 1, :onclick => 'this.form.submit()', :checked =>true %>
<% else %>
   <%= check_box_tag 'catalog_image', 1, :onclick => 'this.form.submit()'%>
<% end %>
```

Comment: `<%= check_box_tag :some_boolean, true, (@somestring == 'true') -%>`
Works just fine